Rounding on Integer Conversion
Dim k1 As Integer = 7.5
Dim k2 As Integer = 6.5
k1==>8
k2==>6
Whats the underlying problem with that inconsistency?

Odd numbers are rounded up, even numbers are rounded down. But you really should not use floating point values for integer variables if you want consistemcy.

What inconsistency?  When you write code that is inconsistent what do you expect?

It's also known as "banker's rounding".

There is no inconsistency. The fact that bad code doesn't do what you expect does not mean that it's inconsistent.

Simply put, vb.net rounds numbers to the nearest even number when they are at a midpoint between the rounding target.
So 1.5 is a midpoint when rounding to a decimal. The nearest even value to 1.5 is 2. You can see the pattern emerge when you round several of these in a row doing something like the below which you can manipulate in this fiddle.
Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        for i As Decimal = 0.5 to 10.5 step 1.0
            Console.WriteLine(i & " casts to " & cInt(i))
        next
    End Sub
End Module

'0.5 casts to 0
'1.5 casts to 2
'2.5 casts to 2
'3.5 casts to 4
'4.5 casts to 4
'5.5 casts to 6
'6.5 casts to 6
'7.5 casts to 8
'8.5 casts to 8
'9.5 casts to 10
'10.5 casts to 10


See this resource for more information on how VB rounds

VB.NET's default mode is to round to the nearest even number when the decimal is at the midpoint (5 in this case) So 7.5 rounds up to 8, 6.5 rounds down to 6. This can be confusing since we were all likely taught in school to round those numbers up to 8 and 7 respectively.  To get around this, use the built-in function: Math.Round and fill in the optional (3rd) parameter: mode.
So for example Math.Round(6.5, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) will return 7
